# joining 2 tables one value

Tags: sql, join, select, magento2

I have 2 tables:

table 1 = relation so column parent_id and column child_id and

table 2 is entity_id and article number.(entity_id = parent and child is)

I want to join/select/union them so that I get a result where instead of de parent_id and child_id I get parent article number and child article number in 2 columns

i'm kinda suck can you guys help plz?

catalog_product_entity

```
Entity ID   SKU
34445       10199
59301       10199001001
```

catalog_product_super_link

```
product_id  parent_id
59301       34445
```

result i want

```
parent sku  child sku
10199       10199001001
```

Comment: I think we will need to you restate the question more coherently.  As far as I can tell your data model doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Please read [why "Can you guys help?" is not a real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like two joins on the second table: one to get the parent, the other for the child:

```
select ap.article_number parent_article_number, ac.article_number child_article_number
from relations r
inner join articles ap on ap.entity_id = r.parent_id
inner join articles ac on ac.entity_id = r.child_id
```

---

**Edit**: this answers the question after table names and columns were changed:

```
select ep.sku parent_sku, ec.sku child_sku
from catalog_product_super_link l
inner join catalog_product_entity ep on ep.entity_id = l.parent_id
inner join catalog_product_entity ec on ec.entity_id = l.product_id
```

Comment: thanks made the query but got error result .
edited question with first row form actual tables

select `catalog_product_super_link`.`parent_id` ,`catalog_product_super_link`.`product_id`
from `catalog_product_entity`
inner join `catalog_product_super_link` on `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_super_link`.`parent_id`
inner join `catalog_product_super_link` on `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_super_link`.`product_id` LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'catalog_product_super_link'

Comment: @dennis: it is not a good practice on SO to substantially modify the question after answer were posted... Still, I edited my answer with a query for your edited question.

Comment: this worked great, thanks it look so simple but i was so stuck on this:)

Comment: thanks for the tip next time i will post the right tables in the answer right away :)